# How to prevent same worksheet from opening

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I  have multiple worksheets shared through Dropbox. I need to detect if the file is already open on another device.

I have tried the code below but the problem is that every time I open a workbook, it says the file is open.

```
Function IsFileOpen(fileName As String)

Dim fileNum As Integer
Dim errNum As Integer

'Allow all errors to happen
On Error Resume Next
fileNum = FreeFile()

'Try to open and close the file for input.
'Errors mean the file is already open
Open fileName For Input Lock Read As #fileNum
Close fileNum

'Get the error number
errNum = Err

'Do not allow errors to happen
On Error GoTo 0

'Check the Error Number
Select Case errNum

    'errNum = 0 means no errors, therefore file closed
    Case 0
    IsFileOpen = False

    'errNum = 70 means the file is already open
    Case 70
    IsFileOpen = True

    'Something else went wrong
    Case Else
    IsFileOpen = errNum

End Select

End Function
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim fileName As String
fileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

'Call function to check if the file is open
If IsFileOpen(fileName) = False Then

    MsgBox "YOU ARE GOOD TO GO"

Else

    'The file is open or another error occurred
    MsgBox " STOP THIS FILE IS ALREADY OPEN."

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why all the capital letters??

Comment: Well, your function is returning *something* other than `True` so the first thing I would do is evaluate what value the function is returning and update your question with that info.